# Cloned GIthub repo not working on my local machine

Tags: html, css, github, fork, clone

I wanted to contribute to this repo here:
https://github.com/thedaviddias/Front-End-Checklist
But when I forked and cloned the project on my computer, I found no HTML or CSS files in the master branch. It is located in the gh-pages branch. I tried to clone only the gh-pages branch, but when running the index.html file there, neither the CSS nor the images loaded up. Am I doing something wrong? Am I supposed to somehow merge the branches together? And if so, how.

Sorry if this is a silly question, I have never contributed to open-source before.

Comment: "Currently working on a V2 of frontendchecklist.io,
feel free to discuss any feature you would like to see in the next version"

I wonder if the repo owner removed the files since he is anticipating a second version to come out. That's what it looks like but some clear communication would help out new contributors such as yourself. You're not doing anything wrong though!

Comment: Thank you! I was so close to giving up on open source altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner hasn't uploaded the index and css files to the repository although they have mentioned how the HTML ad CSS code will work out for the given files in the markdown file . Maybe they did it intentionally or they just don't want to share the source code. Who knows. It is clear that the files are missing.

Comment: Thank you Aadhaar! I will see if I can find other repos that I can contribute to.